# Sun position at sunrise & sunset

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, spheres

There are many many references telling me what time the sun will rise and set. There are also references telling me the sun's latitude on a given day.

But...

I want to find out where the sun will touch the horizon from where I'm standing. 
For instance, right now I'm at a latitude of 38.6799437 N. And the sun is at a latitude of 4.2333333 S.

Now, going off of memory from this morning, the sun came up around a heading of 107°. I want to find out exactly where based on my and the sun's position, which can both vary.

I'm thinking that this is spherical math, but that's more than I ever took. 
I also realize that mountains and buildings will affect the answer a bit, so we'll have to assume a clear site to the horizon.

Thanks

Comment: You will also need to make an assumption about your altitude and height of your eyes from the ground.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation for a start. This subject has been studied in depth for centuries :-). It is actually surprising how well these things were modeled in antiquity (and astronomy, in general, see the Antikythera mechanism).

Comment: @astra. Ok, I guess we'll figure it at 6' . Would it really make a big difference?

Comment: @copper. A little over my head without doing some googling, but that looks like a time formula, and not a location formula. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TomCollins: I just meant that the general subject has been well studied!

Comment: OK, but I haven't been able to find the equations despite a lot of googling. Tons & tons dealing with time, but not bearing.

Answer (score 2):

If you mainly want to know the direction in which the sun will rise, use "Sight Reduction Tables for Marine Navigation"  or the USNO's online sight reduction page.  They tell azimuth to within a tenth of a degree.

"Sight Reduction Tables for Air Navigation" tell it in whole degrees.

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve the notation slightly, using MathJax.  Please feel free to make further edits or revert my edits if they don't match your intention.  It would also be very helpful if you could provide a few links–in particular, you mention a USNO website where some resources can be found; can you please include a link to that?  Links to a useful nautical almanac (if one can be found online), as well as somewhere to obtain sectionals, would be helpful–remember that most of the folk here are mathematicians are likely to be unfamiliar with many of the resource you describe.

Comment: That's good.  The radical symbol is easily recognized and entirely proper.

Comment: When I tried deleting the "x" multiplication symbol the radical symbol then reverted to an  italicized "sqrt".

Comment: The TeX command for the radical is `\sqrt`.  The slash you deleted was important.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thank you.

Comment: What I wrote does not properly answer his question, which is about the direction of the Sun.

Comment: I am considering deleting, and re-answering.

Comment: If there are questions about predicting the TIME of sunrise, I might try answering them.

Comment: I have added an answer.  It is verbatim from the 1934 book.  (The comma after "sin d" was used in the original).